# Caml query doesn't return value

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I have sharepoint 2013 list "Employee" which contents folders with the contact information of employees. There is a field which helps to identify the each employee: Employee GUID. This field has type "Text" and format (example): a3c73e48-d38e-4c83-8ed4-df70d3037cc2.

I want to use query to find employee with  guid which i want. I use the code bellow:

```
string guid = "a3c73e48-d38e-4c83-8ed4-df70d3037cc2";
string sQuery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""Title""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">"+guid+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
                    var oQuery = new SPQuery();
                    oQuery.Query = sQuery;
                    oQuery.Folder = folder;

                    SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(oQuery);
```

And in collListItems.Count i received 0 ! 
But in camlQueryBuilder i receive the employee. And if i use Text field: last name + second name to identify the item i receive the collection of items with such last name + second name and there i found my employee with guid which i want. 

What i do wrong? Explain me please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CAML query specifies that you want to search the `Title` field (where it says `FieldRef Name="Title"`), but the GUID you are looking for would not be in that field. The list items I work with have two GUID fields, one named `GUID` and another named `UniqueId`. These two fields have different values, so you may need to try both to see which holds the value you want.

For the `GUID` field, your query should be like this:

```
string sQuery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""GUID""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">"+guid+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

For the `UniqueId` field, your query should be like this:

```
string sQuery = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=""UniqueId""></FieldRef><Value Type=""Text"">"+guid+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
```